# how to put delay in among multiple task in android

Tags: android

I want to introduce 5-seconds delay while changing the background image of my different BUTTONS dynamically, you can see my code here below. I test number built-in method for delay i.e SLEEP(), WAIT() etc but, it gets sleep my application.

Please somebody help me in developing "myDelayMethod(mSeconds);"

I will be very thakfull to you.

```
int mSeconds =5;//Seconds 

for(number=1; number<5;number++)
{
    if(number==1)
    {
    buttonLED1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    buttonLED1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    }


    else if(number==2)
    {
    buttonLED2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    buttonLED2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    }


    else if(number==3)
    {
    buttonLED3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    buttonLED3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    }


    else if(number==4)
    {
    buttonLED4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonyellow);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    buttonLED4.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
    myDelayMethod(mSeconds);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Button[] buttons = {buttonLED1, buttonLED2, buttonLED3, buttonLED4};

for (Button button : buttons) {

    button.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.buttonblue);
        }
    }, 1000 * mSeconds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to look for `Handler.postDelayed()`.